# How do I get a ViewController for a extra view integrated into the projects main View?

Tags: iphone, sdk

How do I get a ViewController for a extra view integrated into the projects main View?
I want 1 extra UIView in my apps main UIWindow.
How do I get a viewController for the extra UIView?
I want to execute code to it.
Thanks!
I know Im asking alot of similar questions, but im trying different ways of approaching a design.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ModalViewControllers, TabBarViewController, UINavigationController.

Definitely study the [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457) and [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html). These two guides will tell you how to present different screens and when to use View Controllers and Views.